# Dynamic query based on second table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of price quotes for multiple symbols

### Table QUOTES

ID     INT

SYMBOL NVARCHAR(6)

DT     DATETIME

PRICE  DECIMAL(18,5)

### Table TempSymbol

SYMBOL NVARCHAR(6)

I want to extract only those symbols from QUOTES whose symbols are also in a temp table that could vary based on user request

```
Create TABLE TempSymbol
(
   SYMBOL NVARCHAR(6)      NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TempSymbol(SYMBOL) VALUES ('MSFT');
INSERT INTO TempSymbol(SYMBOL) VALUES ('INTC');
INSERT INTO TempSymbol(SYMBOL) VALUES ('AAPL');
```

I want a query that will return from QUOTES the following data...

datetime             symbol1 | price1 | symbol2 | price2 | symbol3 | price3

---

2012-11-12 12:10:00    MSFT  | 12.10  |   INTC  | 5.68   |   AAPL   | 16.89

2012-11-12 12:15:00    MSFT  | 12.22  |   INTC  | 5.97   |   AAPL   | 16.22

....

...

..

```
SELECT DT, SYMBOL, PRICE FROM QUOTE AS Q INNER JOIN TempSymbol AS TS ON Q.SYMBOL = TS.SYMBOL
```

This returns records that I need to pivot but that's not available in SQLite is there an another way I should be attempting this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It ought to work fine as you've given it here in any modern version of SQLite.  What is going wrong?  What do you mean by "pivot"?

Comment: MY query will return ... symbol,datetime.price as rows which need to be pivoted. I need these rows as columns for each datetime column that the symbols in TempSymbol share for each datetime.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is doing the part of your problem that it's designed to do: retrieve the data.  You can add `ORDER BY DT` to make the records for the same date-time adjacent.

If you think about it a minute you'll see that a `SELECT` can't possibly return what you want.  It returns table rows, and SQL table rows have constant length.  So doing what you call a "pivot" is not a `SELECT` operation.  You may be thinking of pivots in spreadsheets.  Databases aren't spreadsheets.

After that, producing the report you want is best done with a little program in any of the languages with an SQLite interface (in Android for example that's Java; otherwise C or TCL).  Make the query.  Get the rows back as hashes, arrays, or ODM records.  The rest is a couple of loops over this data.  The algorithm is:

```
last_dt = null
for row in all rows
  if row.dt != last_dt
    start new output line
    print dt
    last_dt = dt
  end
  print ' | ', row.symbol, ' | ', row.price
end
```

Another note: With advanced DB features like stored procedures and XML objects you could implement this in SQL. XML objects can have variable numbers of fields.   Here the limit is SQLite, which doesn't provide these features.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  In that case I can just programmatically write the query base on what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
SELECT DT, SYMBOL, PRICE FROM QUOTE where SYMBOL in (Select SYMBOL from TempSymbol)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that result returns all records which still requires the pivot with distinct datetime.